# How to combine lower and like in ZF2?

Tags: php, postgresql, zend-framework2, tablegateway

How to get ***SQL*** like this :

```
select * from foo where LOWER(foo_name) like '%test%';
```

I know that I can achieve this:

```
select * from foo where LOWER(foo_name) = 'test';
```

By:

```
$where->addPredicate(new Predicate\Expression('LOWER(foo_name) = ?', 'test' ));
```

And this:

```
 select * from foo where foo_name like '%test%';
```

By:

```
$where->addPredicate( new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Like('LOWER(foo_name)', '%test%'));
```

But how to combine the *two*?

Comment: Just FYI, comparisons with `LIKE` are case insensitive in MySQL. `LOWER()` is not needed at all.

Comment: @fancyPants I am using **PostgreSQL** and it is very case sensitive.

Comment: Then tag the question appropriately.

Comment: ILIKE is your friend for case insensitive like in Postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer given by @dave works fine.

Even this works -

```
$where->expression("LOWER(title) LIKE ?", '%test%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not ideal, but you could do literal:

```
$where->literal("LOWER(foo_name) LIKE '%test%'");
```